# Vale a pena usar o validador W3C?

Tags: html5, w3c-validador

Pergunto isso, porque parece que ele acusa coisas que, acho eu, não era pra acusar.

Por exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Titulo do Site</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Teste Teste Teste" />
        <!--A meta abaixo, diz ao navegador, que terá que inicar na resolução 100%-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=width-device, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--CABEÇALHO DO NOSSO SITE, COMO MENUS< LOGO, ETC-->
        <header>
            <h1>Teste do Documento</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" title="Teste Teste Teste">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#servicos" title="Teste Teste Teste">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portifolio" title="Teste Teste Teste">Portfólio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sobre" title="Teste Teste Teste">Sobre mim</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contato" title="Teste Teste Teste">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <!--CONTEUDO DE NOSSO SITE-->
        <main>
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>Teste Teste Teste</h1>
                    <p>Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste Teste!</p>
                </header>
            </article>
        </main>

        <!--RODAPE DE NOSSO SITE-->
        <footer>
            <h1>Teste</h1>
            <nav>
                <h1>Teste</h1>
                <p>Teste Teste Teste</p>
            </nav>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

É um documento optimizado, mas,no validador, ele da warning de H1:

**Warning: Consider using the h1 element as a top-level heading only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools).**

Sendo que, agora, como o HTML5 cria nós, não há menor problema de usar outros H1, dentro da mesma página, lembrando que tem que está dentro de uma header, article, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vamos ao que diz a especificação do HTML5 sobre as tags do tipo `<h#>`:

> These elements have a rank given by the number in their name. The `h1` element is said to have the highest rank, the `h6` element has the lowest rank, and two elements with the same name have equal rank.

Ainda:

> h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for a new section or subsection.

Ou seja: as tags `<h#>` são feitas para marcar uma seção (independente de estarem dentro de uma tag de sessão ou não. Observe:

```
<section>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h2>Título</h2>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h2>Título</h2>
    <p>Texto</p>
</section>
```

É correto, assim como

```
<section>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <article>
        <h2>Título</h2>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Título</h2>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Ao contrário, estaria errado usar

```
<section>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h1>Título</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <h1>Título</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
</section>
```

Do mesmo jeito que

```
<section>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <article>
        <h1>Título</h1>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h1>Título</h1>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

Isso porque a numeração das tags `h` servem para ranquear um bloco de contexto (ou um sectioning content, como descrito pela W3C). Um sectioning content pode OU NÃO ser delimitado por uma tag, mas ele define a diferença entre um sectioning root e seus filhos.

Seguindo essa lógica, eu não posso ter duas tags consideradas de nível mais alto `<h1>` no mesmo documento, pelo mesmo motivo que eu não posso ter dois sectioning root em relação ao documento.

Ou seja, na marcação

```
<section id="sec1">
    <section id="sec2">
        <section id="sec3">
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

A #sec1 sempre será sectioning root do documento.
A #sec2 é sectioning root em comparação à #sec3. Ainda assim, ele nunca será uma sectioning root em relação ao documento; logo, nunca poderá receber uma tag `h` de nível mais alto (`<h1>`),  que deve pertencer ao sectioning root do documento.

Para se aprofundar na questão:

[The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements)

[Headings and sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections)

[Sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0)

[Outline](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#outline)

**EDIT**

Decidi complementar a resposta para melhor me adequar à pergunta. Como apontado, é importante tanto para interpretadores quando para indexadores que o site siga as regras da W3C, afim de oferecer uma experiência o mais uniforme possível. O ranqueamento pode ser apenas "uma nota" se você ou o seu projeto decidirem ignorar esses parâmetros. Não há erro nisso e o site vai rodar funcionar. Mas, em determinados cenários (como o ranqueamento dos indexadores) não seguir as normas de marcação podem resultar em punições (como índices menores e, consequentemente, piores posições nas listas de busca).

Comment: Essa resposta merece uma recompensa.

Answer (score 6):

O Brunno Vianna, respondeu bem a questão técnica.

Agora Sobre a questão se vale a pena usar o validador tem 2 pontos a serem pesados.

1. Quando seu código está dentro das normas a W3C lhe oferece um selo de qualidade, que você pode colocar em seu site.
2. Para o SEO é ótimo pois ajuda muito os *bots* identificar sobre o que se trata seu site.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, Nathalia!