# Quão importante é de fato validar códigos pela W3C?

Tags: html, css, w3c

Entendo que validar o código pode ser importante e principalmente ajudar quem está começando a corrigir erros e ficar mais informado sobre elementos obsoletos nas atuais versões das linguagens.

Mas quanto devo me preocupar com a validação do meu `HTML` e `CSS`, por exemplo, meu código `HTML` deu um alerta informando que estou utilizando um iframe que possui um atributo frameborder e o mesmo é obsoleto, porém essa parte do código é na verdade um plugin do Faceboook e qualquer coisa que eu altere nessa parte do código ele deixa de funcionar (não sou a favor de usar esses plugins de redes sociais mas foi exigência do cliente).

Esse foi só um exemplo já aconteceu coisas parecidas com bibliotecas ou frameworks que experimentei usar, ou até browser hacks que precisei usar para corrigir problemas de `CSS` em alguns navegadores, e claro que os hacks são acusados como erros na validação.

Atualmente utilizo essa validação da W3C somente para corrigir erros simples que eu deixei passar, e não tento cumprir 100% do que eles indicam.

Portanto, queria saber, até onde vale a pena se esforçar para ter o seu código validado 100% pela W3C, me refiro ao tempo e abrir mão de elementos que você usa mas que não foi você que desenvolveu. Além disso, existe algum beneficio real em ter a validação ou simplesmente é uma correção que te permite sair dizendo por ai que seu código é bom porque a W3C disse que é?

OBS: Não estou defendendo códigos completamente malucos e mal feitos cheios de erros e etc.

Comment: Relacionado: [Vale a pena usar o validador W3C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233704/vale-a-pena-usar-o-validador-w3c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Você precisa dele? se você é um desenvolvedor web ou um web designer
>   está ferramenta será uma poderosa aliada. Ela não só é capaz de
>   comparar uma folha de estilo com as especificações para as CSS,
>   apontando erros, grafia incorreta ou uso impróprio das CSS, mas também
>   alertará você para potenciais riscos à usabilidade.

Fonte: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/about.html.pt-BR

O serviço de validação é uma ferramenta, então cabe a quem esta desenvolvendo avaliar se vale a pena ou não fazer determinadas alterações para ficar de acordo com os padrões do w3c, é sempre bom buscar um código o mais correto possível, mas como o exemplo que você informou, não teve jeito o cliente solicitou algo e você tem que cumprir, será que vale a pena explicar pro cliente o que esta acontecer? Será que o cliente vai querer espera este tempo? Ou arcar com os custos? Isso vai gerar problemas futuros? Tudo isso deve ser levado em consideração na hora da avaliação.

E como esta escrito no próprio link acima:

> É apenas uma ferramenta valiosa e confiável, ressalvado que,
>   sendo uma ferramenta baseada em um software, está sujeita a bugs e
>   incorreções & legacy bugs e incorreções

Ou seja ela é uma ótima ferramenta, ela vai mostrar muitos erros de forma automática, mas ela não conseguirá ter o discernimento do domínio, cabe ao desenvolvedor avaliar no final das contas se deve ou não fazer determinada alteração.